# Calls to the Cloud Firestore API

Tags: ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm bringing a document from Firestore ('users /' + id) like this:

```
this._defaultService.getDatosUser(id).take(1).subscribe(user => {
  this.user = user;
```

});

I get the document correctly. But seeing in Google Cloud Platform, it detects that there have been about 5 calls to 'Read operations in Cloud Firestore'. This in the future would understand that multiplied by five expenses. They are still a beginner and may not understand well the operation of Firestore with angularfire2. Why count five calls and not one?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry  Why count five calls and not one?